# Is it possible to inherit from one swing component but use another for add?

Tags: java

Say I want to create a custom text field like:

```
public class LabledTextField extends JTextField {
    JLabel label;
    JPanel panel;

    public LabledTextField(String labelText, @Nullable String fieldText) {
        super(fieldText);
        label = new JLabel(labelText);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(this);
    }
}
```

When adding this new text field to a container from the outside what I really want to add is the panel. My current workaround is to extend JPanel instead and create methods for setText, getText, addActionListener etc. However is there a better way to tell other components that when they add my custom field they should actually add the JPanel instead?

Comment: Well you'd always be able to do something like `container.add( labeledTF.getPanel() )`.

Comment: If you actually want to use the JPanel, why do you need a new class? You could just create a static method somewhere to construct your JPanel instead...